# AngularJS unable to load page on specified location with hash

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this 2-page website which uses angularjs. I like to be able to load page 1 on a certain position by clicking a link on page 2.

Normally, without angular you would give a div an ID like `<div id="test">` and put a link on page2 `<a href="page1.html#test">test</a>`

On my angular website I use duScroll library to create smooth scrolling.

As a concept I've created the following example website: http://jdenuijl.com/test/#chapter2

this link will open the correct location and smoothscrolls when clicking the links at the top of the page.

On my production website the following link https://escapist.nl/nl/#gallery gets rewritten to https://escapist.nl/nl/#!#gallery and it doesn't open on the correct position.

I've read a lot of questions on stackoverflow about $hashprefix, $locationProvider, $location but I don't see why it's working on my test site and not on my production site. I use some other angularjs functionalities on the production website but I can't find what is causing the rewrite.

What is causing the rewrite and the failure of the normal behaviour?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `#!` is a hash-bang, used for routing in `angular.config`. Your **routes** / states will know where to redirect you depending on that hash location, e.g. `.when("/test"` will be fired upon accessing `website.com/#!/test`. So you have a correct behaviour

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks for your reply. Can you explain why this is not happening in the "test" website?

Comment: there is no routing on that page (no `ngRoute` module/library) for it to even attempt to handle any routing

Answer (score 0):

Aleksey Solovey put me in the right direction. I was using the angular-google-analytics module which I found out was loading ngRoute which caused the problem.